# How do I populate fields and enable buttons only when an item is selected on ListView

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

So, I'm creating a photo library. And I have a listview of photos with labels of the photo under it such as it's name and date as well as buttons next to it which allow you to rename the photo. However, I want all these buttons disabled and labels cleared if there is nothing selected. How and where do I do that in the controller as well as on JavaFX (I'm using scenebuilder by the way)?

Answer (score 3):

Use a binding on the list's selection model:

```
myButton.disableProperty().bind(
    Bindings.isNull(myListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty())
);
```

For your labels you can do something like

```
myLabel.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        // arbitrary logic here...
        var selectedItem = myListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() ;
        if (selectedItem == null) {
            return "" ;
        } else {
            return "some other string" ;
        }
    }), 
    myListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
);
```

All this code can go in your controller's `initialize()` method.

If you have a lot of these, it might be cleaner to use a listener instead:

```
myListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
    // update everything based on the value of newSelection,
    // which will be null if nothing is selected
});
```

Note that with this version, you have to separately make sure everything is initialized to the correct state (by default, nothing will be selected in the list view, so initialize everything to the state you need it when the selection is null)./

Comment: Ok, I have a question about the initialize method. Do I have to add an action event to it or when JavaFX sees it, does it know to call it and keep checking it? And also, how would I do this with fields?

Comment: Neither of those. Just put that code in the initialize method. The binding ensures the state is kept synchronized. From the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/package-summary.html): "A binding observes its dependencies for changes and updates its own value according to changes in the dependencies." (Note I just fixed a bug in the code.)

Comment: What do you mean by "how would I do this with fields?"

Comment: Gotcha. So I just need to write public void initialize(){..} and it'll work? And sorry one more quick question. How do I do this with textFields and Choiceboxes? Do they all have the same .TextProperty() ? I'm assuming that choiceboxes don't.

Comment: `TextField`s have a `textProperty()`, if it's the text you want to make dependent on the selection. `ChoiceBox`es have a `valueProperty()`. All controls (actually, all `Node`s) have a `disableProperty()`.  See the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/package-summary.html). It depends what you want to make dependent on the selection...

Comment: ok thanks a lot. Also, I just want to make sure. All I need to write is public void initialize() {} and fill it out and javaFX will recognize what to do?

Comment: Yes. The `bind(...)` method defined in `Property` (of which `disableProperty()`, `textProperty()`, etc are instances) will do what the API says they will do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211674/discussion-between-minbar-and-james-d).

Comment: I'm getting an error, can I message you about it

Comment: Edit your question to provide more detail. Ideally include a [mcve]